# Не видит и не загружает, ни одно расширение в VS Code. MacBook Pro M1. Mac os Ventura 13.1

Tags: visual-studio-code, mac, расширения, macbook, m1

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Столкнулся вот с такой проблемой в первые.Не видит ни одно расширение, ранее все работало корректно. Может кто сталкивался уже?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

В VSCode нажми F1. Набери в поиске: "user settings". Далее в поиске настроек набери "proxy". В настройках **User -> Application -> Proxy** - Найди пункт "**Http: Proxy Support** (use the proxy support for extensions)". И тут включи "fallback".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]